# Can Google Glass subscribe on GCM messages using GDK?

Tags: google-glass

I want to subscribe on GCM messages inside my GDK glass app. Is it possible to subscribe on GCM messages using GDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old GCM library is still working fine I tested that. It can be downloaded from Android SDK manager.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=176&q=play%20services&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary) bug report on the Mirror API/GDK bug tracker, it is not possible. This is because Google Play Services is not "authentic" on Glass, and as such cannot be used. Since GCM needs Play Services to work, as of now you cannot use GCM. Read the bug report for more infomation on this problem.

However, the depcreciated version of GCM doesn't require Play Services, but it is depreciated, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @AlexeyZakharov Only the depreciated version.